# what happens after I have entered log in password and before the shell prompt comes up? and how to reduce time for that interval?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, boot, startup

I'm doing some experiment on a virtual machine (guest machine is ubuntu 20.04 on arm64) and I'm doing this on a x86_64 host machine (ubuntu 20.04). Right after I login, it takes about a minute until I see the shell prompt.
Here is the log.

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS ab21q-ubuntu-20 ttyAMA0
ab21q-ubuntu-20 login: ckim
Password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-77-generic aarch64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Mon 06 Sep 2021 02:40:15 PM KST

  System load:             0.28
  Usage of /:              32.5% of 19.07GB
  Memory usage:            11%
  Swap usage:              0%
  Processes:               115
  Users logged in:         0
  IPv4 address for enp0s1: 10.0.2.15
  IPv6 address for enp0s1: fec0::5054:ff:fe12:3456

 * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
   footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.

   https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation

114 updates can be applied immediately.
45 of these updates are standard security updates.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable


Last login: Mon Sep  6 12:01:44 KST 2021 on ttyAMA0
```

Because the qemu is emulating arm64 on x86_64 it's basically slow, but I wonder what the OS or startup procedure is doing after I entered the password and before the shell prompt comes up. From the log, it looks like it had checked what packages can be updated through the network. and it also takes some time (~30 secs?) after `Last login: Mon Sep  6 12:01:44 KST 2021 on ttyAMA0` is printed. Is there any way I can skip this long time consuming procedure? (like by setting something in /etc/sysctl.config file)

Answer (score 0):

Read `man login bash` (substitute your `$SHELL`), the "`INVOCATION`" section. You'll find that an "interactive login shell" first reads `/etc/profile`.

Follow what's going on with

```
less /etc/profile
bash -x /etc/profile
```

Answer (score -2):

Apply the "`114 updates`" with `sudo apt upgrade`.  The "How do I suppress warnings ..." story never ends well. Read `man bash login` about "startup files".

Comment: while applying updates is fine advice, it's an answer to another question, not this.

Comment: hi, in this experiement, the OS doesn't need to be updated and it takes very long time so  I wanted to leave it there.(it took about a day to install ubuntu 20.04 on the virtual machine) Probably updating S/W can be the answer. I'll just wait for more answers. Thanks!